# Driver issues: nvidia-driver-390 boots but can't get into nvidia-driver-460

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Big driver issues here... no surprise huh.

The short story: I have a new system and am stoked to do some calculations with CUDA. However, I can't get the latest nvidia drivers to work on it.

The long story: Originally I had an RTX 3090 in there and nvidia-driver-460 was the only available package to use with it. However I could not get it to boot after many many attempts, and I know what you're going to say... nomodeset from grub does *not* work!

I made some progress by removing the 3090 and putting my old GTX 1060 in the box. Then with a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, I got the older package nvidia-driver-390 to install and boot successfully!!! Yet nvidia-driver-460 still does not boot after install. There are no issues on installing the drivers, just an infinite hang on reboot and I can't access recovery mode. I can get a command line maybe every 20 tries by booting from grub with options: nomodeset noapic apci=off 3 .

So my question is, is this a kernel issue? The motherboard? What's going on? Do I just need to wait for bug fixes of some kind? Help!

Hardware:

- Motherboard: ASUS PRIME Z590-V
- CPU: i9-10900k

OS:

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTE
- Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-45 (have also tried 5.8.0-43, no luck)

Comment: The 460 driver should work fine with the 1060 card.  How are you installing the 460 driver?  Are you doing it directly from NVIDIA or using the `graphics-drivers` PPA?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am installing from the graphics-drivers PPA, and have tried many different tacks at this point (PPA, additional drivers GUI, straight from apt, etc.). All lead to the same hang... Also, Secure boot is disabled in BIOS. I can see a note in the driver install that secure boot is indeed disabled, and mokutil confirms.

Comment: One other thing, did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS so that other drivers can be installed that are not signed?

Comment: 460.39 is in the standard repos, no ppas needed.  nomodeset was used to keep the nouveau driver from failing, until the proprietary drivers got installed, so did you try without it?

Comment: Yep, there is no boot with 460 drivers, without nomodeset and with secure boot disabled...

Comment: Here is the install log https://textuploader.com/188de | There are a few oddities in here like "Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory" but they are probably harmless.

Comment: For anyone in the future reading this with a similar problem: I was not able to resolve this, so I have just installed Windows and got to the CUDAing! I am assuming this is some sort of kernel / driver / hardware mismatch, so I will try Ubuntu again next month. Will update again then.

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu.
Try this one.

- `sudo apt purge ~nnvidia`
- `sudo apt autoremove`
- `sudo apt clean`
- `sudo systemctl reboot`

I was using this command in the terminal, and success.